# Error in Derivation for Control Variate Variance?

Tags: variance, minimum-variance

I'm trying to derive the variance for a control variate estimator, but I seem to be missing a term that allows me to end up with the covariance in the final answer.

Let $f(x)$ be my function and let $h(x)$ be my control variate with $x \sim p(x)$. If I define the surrogate function:

$\tilde{f}(x) = f(x) - \beta (h(x) - \mathbb{E}_x[h(x)])$

I'd like to derive the variance of an estimator of the surrogate function:

[image]

As you can see, the middle term should be $Cov(f, h)$. What mistake am I making?

Also, how are there not tags for "control-variates" or "variance-reduction"?

Comment: With respect to your last question, this is a statistics site, not a simulation / programming site!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[f(h-\mathbb{E}[h])] = \text{Cov}(f,h)$, so I'm not sure where you are seeing a mistake.

Comment: @jbowman , I thought $$Cov(f, h) = \mathbb{E}[(f-\mathbb{E}[f])(h-\mathbb{E}[h])]$$. What happened to subtracting the expected value of $f$?

Comment: Also, how are control variates and variance reduction not related to statistics? Topics like these are clearly related to estimators and estimator properties.

Comment: Control variates are pretty much a special-purpose simulation tool, and as such are going to, typically, be discussed within the context of programming and simulation rather than in the context of data analysis or math.  Your question appears on-topic to me, but the reason there isn't a control variate tag is likely that few people with control variate questions come here, instead going to stackoverflow or someplace else.

Comment: I can't help but disagree. Minimum variance estimators are very much a subject in Statistics. Here are lecture notes from Stanford's statistics department https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-basic.pdf

Comment: ... and as your tags show, "minimum-variance" is a tag.  But we are talking about why "control-variates" *isn't* a tag.  If more people ask questions specifically about control variates *on this site*, then it probably will become one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your derivation is correct; the two expressions for $\text{Cov}(f,h)$ referred to in the comments are the same:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(h-\mathbb{E}h)] = \mathbb{E}[fh]-\mathbb{E}[f\mathbb{E}h] \\
= \mathbb{E}[fh]-\mathbb{E}f\mathbb{E}h$$

where the last line follows as $\mathbb{E}h$ is a constant, and the expectation of an r.v. times a constant is just the constant times the expectation.

$$\mathbb{E}[(f-\mathbb{E}f)(h-\mathbb{E}h)] = \mathbb{E}[fh] -\mathbb{E}[f\mathbb{E}h]-\mathbb{E}[h\mathbb{E}f]+\mathbb{E}f\mathbb{E}h \\
=\mathbb{E}[fh] -\mathbb{E}f\mathbb{E}h-\mathbb{E}h\mathbb{E}f+\mathbb{E}f\mathbb{E}h \\
=\mathbb{E}[fh]-\mathbb{E}f\mathbb{E}h$$

Surprising, but true!